# How to apply an animation defined in CSS to a class on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have a class which is just a simple green square. I have made a simple shaking animation but I have not managed to find a way to apply the animation on click. I have tried both jQuery and pure CSS solutions and nothing has worked so far.
The animation:

```
@keyframes hit {
40% {transform: scale(1,1);transform: rotateX(-20deg);transform: rotateY(20deg);transform:rotate(-5deg);}
60% {transform: scale(1.1,1.1);transform: rotateX(20deg);transform: rotateY(-20deg);        }
```

And the class:

```
target-container {
animation-name: none;
animation-duration:0.3s;}
```

The closest I got to making it work was using this function:

```
function hitTarget() {
    target.style.animationName="hit";
    setTimeout(stopAnimation,300);
    function stopAnimation() {
        target.style.animationName="none";
    }
}

target.addEventListener("click",function() {
hitTarget();},false);
```

Comment: You need to add an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example so we can help you.

Comment: Also, "attack" defines an attack value which I will use later, ignore it as it's not relevant.

Comment: I have removed unimportant data to make the example minimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few issues with your code - not sure if they're a result of working them into the question, or part of your actual code. So let's go through them.

1. I think I had to fix some syntax errors in the CSS - missing closing `}` (bracket).
2. Also, to define multiple `transforms` just list all transforms in a single `transform` style. Like `transform: rotate(2deg) scale(1.2)`.
3. Instead of passing an anonymous function which calls the `hitTarget` function, we'll pass the `hitTarget` function as the callback to the event listener.
4. Finally, instead of adding/removing the `animation-name` I'd recommend adding/removing a CSS class, which applies the animation.

Here it is all cleaned up and working:

```js
function hitTarget(event) {
  const animationClass = "withAnimation";
  event.target.classList.add(animationClass);
  setTimeout(stopAnimation, 300);

  function stopAnimation() {
    event.target.classList.remove(animationClass);
  }
}

document.querySelector(".target-container").addEventListener("click", hitTarget, false);
```

```css
@keyframes hit {
  40% {
    transform: scale(1, 1) rotateX(-20deg) rotateY(20deg) rotate(-5deg);
  }
  60% {
    transform: scale(1.1, 1.1) rotateX(20deg) rotateY(-20deg);
  }
}

.target-container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

.withAnimation {
  animation-name: hit;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="target-container"></div>
```